# Menu de flutuante em um Webview - UWP

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-10

Desejo que você poderia me orientar em uma coisa. Como fazer quando clico no botão direito do mouse em um link aberto em um `Webview` abrir um menu de opções com funções como *copiar link* e *abrir link*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para interagir com `Webview` dessa maneira é necessário trabalhar com [InvokeScriptAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_System_String___) e [ScriptNotify](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView?redirectedfrom=MSDN#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_ScriptNotify).

Basicamente, um evento é disparado quando um determinado comando de um `script` é executando dentro do `Webview` (ver referências para mais detalhes).

Neste exemplo o `script`procura pela tag `<a>` para que um evento seja disparando sempre que o botão direito do mouse for pressionado no `script` utilizado aqui (*contextmenu*) é responsável por 'simular' esta ação. (`js` não é meu forte)

**Xaml do Webview**:

```
<WebView Grid.Row="1" Name="WebView" 
                Margin="5,5,5,5"
                NavigationCompleted="WebView_OnNavigationCompleted"
                ScriptNotify="WebView_OnScriptNotify"
                Source="http://google.com.br"/>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
private async void WebView_OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
            {
                "var Anchors = document.getElementsByTagName(\"a\");" +
                "for (var i = 0; i < Anchors.length ; i++) {" +
                "    Anchors[i].addEventListener(\"contextmenu\", " +
                "        function (event) {" +
                "            window.external.notify(this.href);" +
                "        }," +
                "        false);" +
                "}"
            });
        }

    private void WebView_OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        var pointer = Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition;
        var url = e.Value;

        Ppup.HorizontalOffset = pointer.X - 300;
        Ppup.VerticalOffset = pointer.Y - 60;

        Ppup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Dentro do script que é 'injetado' através do `WebView.InvokeScriptAsync` `window.external.notify(this.href)` é responsável por 'notificar' o `Webview` (`WebView_OnScriptNotify`)

---

É necessário definir as `urls` que podem utilizar `window.external.notify` para disparar eventos, para isso, no seu `package.appxmanifest` (*botão direito no projeto > propriedades*) adicione conforme exemplo mostrado na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código fonte:
https://github.com/rubgithub/WebViewScriptNotify

Referencias:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Popup-Control-in-universel-700d46d4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746705/how-can-i-move-the-mouse-in-a-uwp-app
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Invoke-ScriptNotify-event-4e9e13a4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041593/adding-click-event-via-addeventlistener-to-confirm-navigation-from-a-hyperlink/6042019#6042019

Comment: Muito obrigado me ajudou muito.

Comment: Por nada, aproveite e também vote positivo `▲` na resposta. @MacleySousa